# Set up BranchIo with Ionic 5 and Capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, branch.io, capacitor, ionic5

I am migrating from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5 and Cordova to Capacitor. I am facing problems in using BranchIo plugin which is working perfectly in Ionic 3. I have installed the plugin for Capacitor as per this [document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/branch-io) with the following.

```
npm install branch-cordova-sdk
npm install @ionic-native/branch-io
ionic cap sync
```

There are no errors in installation. 
Now I can not follow this [document](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/cordova-phonegap-ionic) for Cordova as I am using Capacitor. So I am trying to set up my native app in Adroid Studio as per this [Branch document](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration) for Android Basic Integration.

The only code I was able to add without error in the following in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<!-- Branch init -->
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_xxxxxxxx" />
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test_xxxxxxxx" />
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" />



<!-- Branch App Links (optional) -->
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xxxx.app.link" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xxxx-alternate.app.link" />
</intent-filter>
```

Other than this any suggested code I am adding is giving error. Like adding the following line in `<application>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:name="com.eneff.branch.example.android.CustomApplicationClass"
```

Can anyone please provide guidance to set up BranchIo with Ionic 5 and Capacitor?

Note: I also tried to use the Capacitor community plugin [capacitor-branch-deep-links](https://github.com/boundstate/capacitor-branch-deep-links) but this plugin only has methods to listen to links but no methods to create link.

**UPDATE:**

I am able to get the link created by Branch method `createBranchUniversalObject` but the link is not formatted. I am getting the following full link.

```
https://bnc.lt/a/key_test_xxxxxx?feature=share&type=0&duration=0&source=android&data=xxxxxx
```

This link is opening the correct page as well. The only part not working is the link is not converter to the short Branch link.

Comment: Have you done this task with BranchIo?

Answer (score 1):

A Branchster Here -

Currently we have an internal ticket to provide support for Capacitor, but it doesn't have a deadline yet. For Cordova SDK you can refer to our docs - https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/cordova-phonegap-ionic

For Capacitor we do have a feature request but don't have a timeline set.
You can also go through the Github issue for reference - https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking-attribution/issues/528
​​​​​​

Though there is also a community [plugin](https://github.com/boundstate/capacitor-branch-deep-links) which you may refer to but it's not official and might cause unknown issues.

I'll keep this post updated with future SDK developments.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Looking forward to get something for the Capacitor.

Comment: now capacitor branch released, https://github.com/BranchMetrics/capacitor-branch-deep-links

Comment: But no support yet for Capacitor 3?

Comment: is it updated to capacitor 3?